# Find cell address via VBA through user form

Tags: excel, vba

Alright so, this is my first time fiddling with VBA in a little over a decade, and the actual first time trying to apply it to excel.

I have a range “C7:G19”
I have a series of labels on my user form named Label9 through Label14
Each of those Labels has a Tag that corresponds to the values in the first column of my range (“C7:G19”)

Now, what I’m needing to do is rig it so that when I click a command button, the code will find the address of the cell in the 5th(“G”) column of the row containing a value that matches a search key obtained from the Tag values of the Labels I mentioned above.

Now, I have two spreadsheet functions that do exactly what I want them to, the problem is I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the VBA code equivalent without getting a runtime error

Here’s the spreadsheet functions:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(C7:G19,MATCH(“hard coded value”, C7:C19,0),1)),7)
=CELL(“address”,INDEX(C7:C19,MATCH(“hard coded value”,C7:C19,0),5))
```

Both of these return the correct cell address.

Here’s what I have so far for code

```
For n = 9 to 14
search_key = user_form(“Label” & n).Tag
data_address = Application.WorksheetFunction.ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(Range(“C7”,”G19), MATCH(search_key, Range(“C7”, “C19”), 0), 1)),7)
MsgBox = data_address
Next n
```

Edit: I skipped over an error. The above returns an error telling me that the MATCH function is not defined, so I went back in and added the Application.WorksheetFunction thing to each part of the formula and that’s where I get the runtime error

This uniformly returns “Runtime Error ‘438’: Object doesn’t support this properly or method” and I’m not entirely sure what I need to do here. I can hard code the cell addresses, they aren’t going to change, but I’d rather not.

Answer (score 0):

For now, forget the loop and try only one line of your code.

Only on this line :

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(Range(“C7”,”G19), MATCH(search_key, Range(“C7”, “C19”), 0), 1)),7)
```

you have a lot of mistakes. For the reference to the cell G19 a double quotes is missing. And I don't know what will be the error message for Range(“C7”,”G19”).

And try to put only a small part of your code in a new procedure to test something, like :

```
Sub Test()
     MsgBox Range(“C7”,”G19”)
End Sub

Sub Test()  
     search_key = user_form(“Label9).Tag
     MsgBox search_key
     MsgBox MATCH(search_key, "Your range", 0), 1)
End Sub
```

And with your instruction:

```
MsgBox = data_address
```

It is certain you will have an error message.

Comment: The missing double quote there was a typo  I’m at work and doing this on a workstation here that doesn’t have external net access so I had to type all that on my phone instead of being able to just copy/paste it. 

The MsgBox is just there to see if I got the thing to work or not, but the debug window returns the data_address variable as empty, so I’m guessing that is either the cause of the error, or the result of it. But I shall go see what happens with your code above! Thank you!

Comment: Alright, so the breakdown is coming when I try to get the address using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Cell()` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.Address()`

Comment: So I’m guessing that those two functions are just not available, or I’m missing a step to get the text result

Comment: `Sub Test()
search_key = user_form(“Label9”).Tag
row_key = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(search_key, Range(“C1”, “C19”), 0)
Range(“G” & row_key) = [new_value]
End Sub`

Comment: The mobile site won’t let me format properly in comments, sorry for the jumble, but that little daisy chain does exactly what I need it to!